# image -> video -> image not lossless using avconv

Tags: codec, avconv

I'm trying to test the amount of information lost with some different video codecs. I've got a python script which uses PyPNG to write a series of 8 bit RGB images. I then encode it using avconv, for instance

```
avconv -r 1 -i ../frames/data%03d.png -c:v ffv1 -qscale:v 0 -r 1
```

outffv1.avi

I then decode this back into pngs like so

```
avconv -r 1 -i outffv1.avi -r 1 ./outffv1/frame%03d.png
```

But when I compare the images before and after the video compression, they are different (mean absolute error of ~~15%). The thing that is confusing me is that this is true (give or take) *independent of the codec*.

For instance, I get similar answers for libtheora for a range of qscale values.

The png encoding i.e. write to png, and immediately load back in without and video compression step, is lossless.

UPDATE - more precise worked example:

Single input frame here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2utk1xs2t8heai9/data001.png?dl=0
Encoded to video like this: `avconv -r 1 -i ./frames/data%03d.png -c:v ffv1 -qscale:v 0 -r 1 outffv1.avi`
resultant video here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g1babae2a41v914/outffv1.avi?dl=0
decoded to a png again here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8i8zg1qn7dxsgat/out001.png?dl=0
using this command: `avconv -r 1 -i outffv1.avi -qscale:v 31 -r 1 out%03d.png`
and image magick differenced like this
`compare out001.png ./frames/data001.png diff.png`
to give this (non-zero) diff
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vpouk54p0dieqif/diff.png?dl=0

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you mean to say that you didn't expect png encoding to be lossless? PNG supports loss-less coding

Comment: I expect/want the avconv encoding from video to png to be lossless. Do you know if it is, or how to make it so?

Comment: @nrob Can you share a sample png? How are you comparing?

Comment: I'm loading them into python using pypng and then comparing using numpy. Here's a sample png https://www.dropbox.com/s/9qc0809kyqm4pi5/data000.png?dl=0

Comment: @nrob Using the original 4K image with `ffmpeg` and `ffv1` failed for me due to int limits, I have to see what's wrong since I'm on x64. Encoding the provided PNG scaled to 2048x2048 to `ffv1` (which is lossless) in `AVI` and extracting the frames showed no differences with imagemagick's `compare`. Theora is lossy AFAIK.

Comment: Im confused then - because that's not what happened when I did it. I'll update the question with a more precise, stripped down example with data. btw I mentioned the Theora because it was apparently the same data loss as ffv1, which suggested that the data wasn't lost in the video compression, but somewhere else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your video file most likely uses the YUV color format. PNG uses RGB. The conversion of the color is not a lossless process.